# "What is the point" or "What is the purpose"

Tags: word-usage, difference, word-meaning

I am wondering what is the exact difference between "What is the point" and "What is the purpose" ?
I was answering to a question on an other SE forum and I just told "What is the point of this ?", now I am wondering if isn't sort of "more agressive" than "What is the purpose of this ?"

Comment: generally, the *point* is short and precise and *purpose*, as compared to *point* will be in detail and explanatory.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/point. Be careful with the subtle differences between the senses 15, 16, and 17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on the context. Both can mean the same and different.

Consider these examples

> "We should keep our customer happy. We should provide the best service. We should be ready answering them any time... blah ...blah...blah..."; "Okay, what's the point"; "The **point is,** we should be a **client centric organization.**

Think this same topic but now with *purpose*...

> "We should keep our customer happy. We should provide the best service. We should be ready answering them any time... blah ...blah...blah..."; "Okay, what's the purpose"; "The **purpose is** to focus on our customer service and make them satisfied. That will bring more customers and our sales will double."

As I said, broadly, both *[point (#7)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=point)* and *[purpose](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=purpose)* mean the same.

Comment: Thank you ! It's much more clear now ! I see that you put a comma after "the point is", are we forced to put a comma "after the point is" ? And is it correct to say "The point is that we should be a client centric organization" ?

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise that's an all different question - to put comma or not. In that sentences, that can go *without* comma as well. I put comma to emphasize a gap. Yes, this is fine - *the point is that we should....*